# EXCEL Sum values in last column under a merged header

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheets like in "Picture1" below where the several columns are repeated per month year and I want to sum all the values under the column called "Cost remaining" but based on the month year value in the merged cell above it.

for example if I enter in Cell A1 February 2017 I want to sum the values in the column "Cost remaining" under the merged cell of February 2017 which is as per the picture below the values located in ES11:ES105 and if I entered March 2017 in Cell A1 I need the formula to sum FA11:FA105

the problem is that I can't seem to be able to locate the last column under each month nor able to know what is the last row in the month table.

can you advise on the best way to accomplish what I need. as I'm new to VBA and couldn't find any combination of excel formulas to accomplish this goal.

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFLiA.png)

I found a code and I tweaked it to get the first cell in the required column so far
the code is:

```
 Sub Select_Range()
Dim Fm As Range, Av As Range, rng As Range, rngEnd As Range
Dim s As String, x

s = "February 2017 (IN/OUT)"
Set Fm = Rows(8).Find(s, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not Fm Is Nothing Then
    Set Av = Fm.MergeArea

    Set rng = Av.Offset(3).Resize(, Av.Columns.Count)
    Set rngEnd = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    rngEnd.Select
End If
```

End Sub

all I need now is to figure out how to get the last row number and the rest should be easy.

I think I'm close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a solution to do the trick even my VBA skills are poor now the reminder is just to supply the value of s through a parameter and return the value of x and call this code as normal excel function

```
 Sub Sum_Specific_Month()
Dim FoundR As Range, Av As Range, StartR As Range, SumR As Range
Dim s As String, x
Dim lRow As Long

s = "February 2017 (IN/OUT)"
Set FoundR = Rows(8).Find(s, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not FoundR Is Nothing Then
    Set Av = FoundR.MergeArea

    Set StartR = Av.Offset(3).Resize(, Av.Columns.Count)
    Set StartR = StartR.Cells(StartR.Rows.Count, StartR.Columns.Count)
    Set SumR = Range(StartR, StartR.End(xlDown))
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumR)
    Range("EN3").Value = x

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: To be able to help you, you must make some things clear first. Where do you want x to be returned?

Comment: Thank @dimitris I have made this as function not a sub and returned x as a return value of the function

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
Sub locate_column_n_row()
    Dim nextMonth As Range
    Dim thisMonthColumn As Long
    Dim thisMonthRow As Long


    'Use Find function to locate the next month.
    'To find the desired column for February, you must search for March.
    'In your example this will return Range("ET8"):
    Set nextMonth = Rows(8).Find("March 2017", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    'Now find the desired column of the previous month. In your example subtract by 4:
    thisMonthColumn = nextMonth.Column - 4

    'The following expression returns the row of the last-cell-that-has-a-value in a given column.
    thisMonthRow = Cells(Rows.Count, thisMonthColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    'I think this will locate the last row in the month table,
    'on condition that every other cell under this (in this column), doesn't have any values.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you what you wrote is very helpful I'm tweaking it to my end I'll post how I find the sum when I'm done

Comment: You are welcome. If you liked the information provided, you could accept it as an answer though.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a little table like this:

```
Month - Column 
---------------
February - "ES"
March - "FA"
```

Then, you use VLOOKUP to get the column according the month and use the INDIRECT function into the SUM to set the range

Did I make myself clear?

Comment: Yes clear however the problem is that if I inserted a column between the column "quantity" and column "Total exit" and this happens frequently then ES would change into something else

Comment: I see, so you can use a formula or vba function to find the column "Cost remaining" wherever it is

Comment: Correctluckily I solved it and posted the solution as a vba Sub here however at the end for my purposes I turned it into a function